# mariadb-server-10.0 conflicts with mysql-server-core-5.5 on debian-jessie

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian-jessie

I have mysql up and running

```
akd6:/etc/apt# mysql -V 
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.32-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
akd6:/etc/apt#
```

I have in my debian8 installed `mariadb-server-core-10.0  10.0.31` and the meta-package: `mariadb-server`:

```
akd6:~# dpkg -l | grep -E 'mariad|mysql-' | grep -v lib
ii  mariadb-client-10.0                  10.0.32-0+deb8u1                         amd64        MariaDB database client binaries
ii  mariadb-client-core-10.0             10.0.32-0+deb8u1                         amd64        MariaDB database core client binaries
ii  mariadb-common                       10.0.32-0+deb8u1                         all          MariaDB common metapackage
iU  mariadb-server                       10.0.32-0+deb8u1                         all          MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mariadb-server-10.0                  10.0.31+maria-1~jessie                   amd64        MariaDB database server binaries
ii  mariadb-server-core-10.0             10.0.31+maria-1~jessie                   amd64        MariaDB database core server files
ii  mysql-common                         10.0.31+maria-1~jessie                   all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
akd6:~#
```

when I run `apt-get -f install`:

```
akd6:/etc/apt# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
Suggested packages:
  mariadb-test tinyca
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 101 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,214 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 191964 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-server-core-10.0 (10.0.32-0+deb8u1) over (10.0.31+maria-1~jessie) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/innochecksum.1.gz', which is also in package mariadb-server-10.0 10.0.31+maria-1~jessie
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb containing mariadb-server-10.0:
 mariadb-server-10.0 conflicts with mysql-server-core-5.5
  mariadb-server-core-10.0 provides mysql-server-core-5.5 and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-server-10.0
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
akd6:/etc/apt#
```

Comment: Did you use a third party repo in the past to install `mariadb`? `+maria-1~jessie` indicates that, this naming scheme isn't use in `Debian`. If so, `remove` these versions, but don't use `purge`, and proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you try to install package `mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb` while `mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.31+maria-1~jessie`. The latter one provides (among others) the same files that are in the `mysql-server-core-5.5` package. Maybe that's why you get the

```
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.32-0+deb8u1_amd64.deb containing mariadb-server-10.0:
 mariadb-server-10.0 conflicts with mysql-server-core-5.5
  mariadb-server-core-10.0 provides mysql-server-core-5.5 and is present and installed.
```

error. It seems that the exact problem and solution is described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/upgrade-mariadb-10-0-29maria-1jessie-failed

Comment: It's not the exact same problem. The problem here seems to be the use of a third party repository, see my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have mysql and maridb installed on the same machine, mariadb binaries are the same name as those in mysql.
So you need to choose which one you want, and uninstall the other.

Comment: effectively @chilladx I have two meta packages `mysql-common` and `mariadb-common` but both install mariadb so what to do ?

Comment: uninstall one of them, because you don't need both (anyway, you can't have both)

Comment: akd6:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-core-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.32-0+deb8u1) but 10.0.31+maria-1~jessie is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
akd6:/etc/apt/sources.list.d#